# Python create an array from dictionary

Tags: python

I'm not sure if this is the correct title for what I want to do but, I have a list at the same level and want to use "vlan" as the top level and the "name" as an attribute. Below is the list.

```
vlans = ['vlan 1', 'name default', 'vlan 2', 'name non-default']
```

Code to create a dictionary. Not sure if I need to do this.

```
for v in vlans:
    type = v.split(" ")
    value = dict([(type[0], type[1])])
    print(value)
```

Output

```
{'vlan': '1'}
{'name': 'default'}
{'vlan': '2'}
{'name': 'non-default'}
```

The reply marked as answer will work in this situation. Could this output also be achieved?

```
{
    "vlan 1":{
        "name": "default"
    },
    "vlan 2":{
        "name": "non-default"
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you *expect* as output.

Comment: This is not creating a single dictionary but a list of dictionaries

Comment: It is a bit unclear what the actual question is. Do you not know how to append the results in to a list?

Comment: Do you mean an array or a list?  `array` is a standard library module, and numpy uses its own arrays, so in Python arrays and lists are not the same.

Comment: not sure what you really want, if you want a dict, the keys are duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you're looking for, so here's a guess :

```
vlans = ['vlan 1', 'name default', 'vlan 2', 'name non-default']
output = {}

for i in range(len(vlans)/2):
    output[vlans[2*i]] = vlans[2*i + 1]
```

This produces `{'vlan 1': 'name default', 'vlan 2': 'name non-default'}`
Is it what you meant by :

> use "vlan" as the top level and the "name" as an attribute

**EDIT :** As an afterthought, maybe you wanted to get rid of "vlan" and "name" everywhere. Here is a way to do this.

```
vlans = ['vlan 1', 'name default', 'vlan 2', 'name non-default']
output = {}

for i in range(len(vlans)/2):
    vlan_number = (vlans[2*i].split())[1]
    name = (vlans[2*i + 1].split())[1]
    output[vlan_number] = name
```

This produces the output :

```
{'1': 'default', '2': 'non-default'}
```

Please note that here the vlan numbers are strings. To have them as integers, just convert them in the last line for instance :

```
output[int(vlan_number)] = name
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure how to ask my question but the output you produced is what I am looking for.